# converting nvarchar(50) to datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2005, nvarchar

I am using SQL Server 2005 and am trying to match in a Dimension table the date field with data:

`2012-01-06 00:00:00.000` as a `datetime`
to a staging table with data that comes in as a `nvarchar(50)`
    `2012-01-06 15:53:12.040`
for example.  I have tried all of the converts and casts that I can find on the searches but am getting an "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime." error message.

I have updated all of the time values manually in the staging table to have `00:00:00.000` time stamps but still the problem is there.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-06 15:53:12.040') working without any issue at my SQL 2012 sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to change the data type of the entire column?

If so, try this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datetime
```

More [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx).

If you are trying to just modify for a query, you can try this:

```
 SELECT convert (...look at link below for options... )
```

Look [here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) for more info.